# Restricting price option to a group

Tags: price-sets

According to this answer [Can I offer different pricing for an event based on user group?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16293/can-i-offer-different-pricing-for-an-event-based-on-user-group) it is possible to restrict a price option that is set up as a check box, radio button or selection to a group.
However, I don't see the option to limit the option to a specific group?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're referring to says you need the [Group-Based Pricing](https://github.com/zengenuity/civicrm_groupprice) extension installed.  It also seems that the extension isn't being maintained, and folks have had to tweak it to work with modern versions of CiviCRM.  [This fork](https://github.com/tadpolecc/civicrm_groupprice) seems more up-to-date.